# How to set winform checkboxlist items checked when clicked on checkbox or its text?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkboxlist

I am using checkbox list control in my window form application. When user click on any row then that row becomes blue and we get its checked status by following code

```
private void clbRoles_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
.
.
.
}
```

How to make selection of checkbox only on clicking on checkbox or its text ?

Not by clicking on row outside the checkbox text area.

Comment: Selection is different from checking. What the question is about? Please elaborate more about the problem and the expected behavior.

Comment: seems so to me that you have a row_click event that changes the value of the box if i understood correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Something in your code (maybe an event handler, as @markorial suggests), is causing that behaviour. Take into account that with a code like the one below, you can only click in the checkbox itself (or its label) in order to activate it.

```
class CheckBoxesWindow: Form {
    public Window()
    {
        this.Build();

        var row1 = new ListViewItem( "Do the dishes", 0 );
        row1.SubItems.Add( "High" );
        row1.Checked = true;

        var row2 = new ListViewItem( "Wash sheets", 1 );
        row2.SubItems.Add( "Average" );

        this.lvView.Items.AddRange( new ListViewItem[]{ row1, row2 } );
    }

    void Build()
    {
        var lv = this.BuildListView();

        this.Controls.Add( lv );
        this.Show();
    }

    ListView BuildListView()
    {
        int width = this.ClientSize.Width;
        var toret = new ListView{ Dock = DockStyle.Fill };

        toret.View = View.Details;
        toret.CheckBoxes = true;
        toret.Columns.Add( "Desc", (int) ( width * 0.70 ), HorizontalAlignment.Center );
        toret.Columns.Add( "Priority", (int) ( width * 0.30 ), HorizontalAlignment.Right );

        this.lvView = toret;
        return toret;
    }

    ListView lvView;
}
```

Hope this helps.